# Ionic Facebook Login logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, ionic-framework, authentication

im working on an app using ionic and Rest api with .net core 
for the login and register it works fine 
but when im thinking about adding social login and register using facebook and google i cant get the logic for saving my infos in my DB
for exemple facebook can give me email, picture, name .. but not password 
if a new clinet sign in to the app how i can save the infos to database without password ?
and how i can log in with facebook and pick the user data from database without a password and using only an email.

i need only the logic for this or any example

thank you

Comment: when user login with google, well people can display who is logged in and their data like email and name that time you can save current user data in your data base well i did something similar to this using firebase maybe it work in google & facebook too.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best answer but what I did in a previous app was to use Firebase to handle Facebook login. Then you can store the UID in your DB.

Another resource that I haven't looked at, but you could check out is [this Microsoft doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2)